# DHT21 / AM2301 sensor not measuring humidity Arduino

Tags: arduino, temperature, 5v

Although there was a similar thread it was for Raspberry PI. This sensor should work out of the box with the Arduino and should be more advanced than the cheap DHT11/22.

I have this exact sensor:  Arduino AM2320B Digital Temperature Humidity Sensor module SHT21 AM2301 B2AD

With the sample code I get the Temperature properly but the Hum: nan

I tried using 2 pullups to 5V as it was suggested (doesn't make any difference).

I have tried multiple sensors in case it might be broken but it's the same with all.

Circuit + Code used:

https://lastminuteengineers.com/am2320-temperature-humidity-sensor-arduino-tutorial/

Comment: You need to add more information. It's a simple circuit but a circuit diagram would be useful to add nonetheless. Include the exact code you're using and include your outputs instead of just describing what you're seeing. Also: have you tried any solutions so far? If you're seeing Hum:nan, then I'm guessing you're using a library - have you checked out the documentation of the library for common troubleshooting?

Comment: The AM2301 uses a very simple serial protocol to read both the humidity and temperature values in one 40-bit string, which includes a checksum. If temperature is returned correctly, but humidity isn't, it seems unlikely that the problem is in the connection between the device and the MPU. The problem might be with your software not properly decoding the values returned.

Comment: Added. I using the latest libraries.

Comment: Perhaps try also another library.

Comment: Perhaps not? I'm sorry but this should be a high quality sensor better than the cheap dht11/22. Why is it such a garbage product? This should work out of the box without any hacking with an Arduino.